# How to return array or JSON object using function ST_AsMVT in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, mapbox

I am working in PostgreSQL/PostGIS and could you please explain me how I can return an array or json object data in the tiles using **ST_AsMVT** function.

Right now I am using GeoJSON to return an array or json object, and for big data it is sadly...

When I put an array into the tiles and try to use the ST_AsMVT function and return this on the frontend (mapbox), I can't use the array field here...

Could you give me an example of how I can do it (maybe something with jsonb)...?

Comment: Nested and/or (semi-, un-) structured data types are not part of the Vector Tile specification, and are implemented differently, if at all, across client frameworks. AFAIK Mapbox GL has support for specifically formatted key/value & array *string literal* parsing out of the box.

Comment: I'm not sure of the internals but pg_tileserv does this just fine - we are using it in production - you could look at that code and see if it triggers any ideas. It's on GitHub.

Comment: @Malcolm
Interesting, but pg_tileserv is bad and slowly thing (my opinion). I can create tiles in the DB then call them from API to Frontend (mapbox) that's better and faster.

Comment: pg_tileserv is as fast as the CPUs that run it -